# Printing 4 columns to A4

Tags: pdf, printing, google-docs, print-to-pdf, pdfcreator

I want to print 4 columns onto an A4 sheet of paper to create an instructional pamphlet that can be folded up.  Unfortunately Google Docs only supports up to 3 columns.

I am using Google Docs and have set the page size to exactly the size of 1/4th an A4 in landscape, which is really great for layout and word processing.

[Here is our document to be printed.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/125VglijTdql9H-Xc94iakTOyrM5jkWPQ/view?usp=sharing)

Now how can I get this printed side by side on an A4 page in landscape?  Is there a PDF tool I can use to splice my pages together?  Or perhaps a printing tool that will let me arrange them side by side?

We do not have access to MS Word, Excel or any paid-for Adobe products.  Preferably I'd like to do this at no cost, but willing to pay if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [PDF-XChange editor](https://portableapps.com/apps/office/pdf-xchange-editor-portable). It is free to use and also well mantained.

Open your file, go to `File > Print`. Click on page setup, select `A4` size and `Landscape` orientation. Next, under `Page placement and scalings` select Type to `Multiple pages per sheet`. Now, enter `4` by `1` in `Pages per sheet`. You can change other printing settings if you want to. Final settings will look like this:

[image]

You can also use the free version of [`Foxit Reader`](https://www.foxit.com/downloads/#Foxit-Reader/) for the purpose.

Comment: Excellent - thank you for your answer